# Is it possible to know the action in the class form (Symfony)?

Tags: forms, symfony1, action

Is it possible to know the action performed by the user (New, Update) at the form class level (Form.class.php)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the underlying object is **new** or **exists** in the database:

`$this->getObject()->isNew()`